# Is there a better way to manipulate column names in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a large dataframe and need a way to dynamically rename column names.

*Here's a slow method I'm working with:*

```
# Create a sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([
    {'Name':'Jay','Favorite Color (BLAH)':'Green'},
    {'Name':'Shay','Favorite Color (BLAH)':'Blue'},
    {'Name':'Ray','Favorite Color (BLAH)':'Yellow'},
])

# Current columns are: ['Name', 'Favorite Color (BLAH)']

# ------

# build two lambdas to clean the column names
f_clean = lambda x: x.split('(')[0] if ' (' in x else x
f_join = lambda x: '_'.join(x.split())
df.columns = df.columns.map(f_clean, f_join).map(f_join).str.lower()

# Columns are now: ['name', 'favorite_color']
```

**Is there a better method for solving this?**

Comment: how about using `df.reindex` ? or simply renaming the columns again ?

Comment: _I'm not familiar with reindexing._ Renaming would be difficult with a massive df.

Comment: By massive do you mean massive in terms of the number of columns, or there's just a lot of rows? I feel like adjusting just the `df.columns` Index object would be extremely fast.

Comment: Would `df.rename(name_map, inplace=True)` be faster?
you'd have to construct `name_map` to be a dict keyed by current col name and valued by the new col name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a `clean` function and just apply to all the columns using list comprehension.

```
def clean(name):

  name = name.split('(')[0] if ' (' in name else name
  name = '_'.join(name.split())
  return name

df.columns = [clean(col) for col in df.columns]
```

It's clear what's happening and not overly verbose.